# odd phpmyadmin_xxx databases on a centos6 / plesk 11 server

Tags: phpmyadmin, plesk, centos6

I'm working on a hosted server running centos and plesk 11.1.
apache, mysql, plesk and other friends are up and running -now..- but Im wondering what are these databases :

```
drwx------  2 mysql mysql     4096 Feb 24  2013 phpmyadmin_Axxyxxupxxyd
drwx------  2 mysql mysql     4096 Apr 10  2013 phpmyadmin_Qazy9yyyM98C
drwx------  2 mysql mysql     4096 Sep  7  2012 phpmyadmin_zzzzzZzzzkct
drwx------  2 mysql mysql     4096 May 28  2013 phpmyadmin_yTbbbbbbbbbb
drwx------  2 mysql mysql     4096 Feb 17  2013 phpmyadmin_aaaaaaaa78cv
```

their tables have a pma_ suffix. all the same size, almost empty.

are they forgotten phpmyadmin-plesk sessions I could drop with no collateral damage, or is there something important I need to know ?

Many thanks, 
Jerome

Comment: I know that Plesk creates new phpMyAdmin database on every major plesk upgrade. May be there was several upgrade attempts which are triggers new database creating for phpMyAdmin.

Comment: thanks for the info. will try to remove the sep 7 2012 one...

Comment: Do you see any corresponding databases listed from within MySQL/phpMyAdmin?